# Rails 4.2.8 - rake test isn't producing any output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have an existing Rails 4.2.8 project which had a missing `test` directory. So I created a new, separate 4.2.8 project, and copied over the `test` directory to it (which already has a couple of working models tests).

But when I run `bundle exec rake test`, I'm not getting any terminal output. I have output for all other types of rake commands, but running `rake test` produces nothing. I've tried putting put statements in various places like inside the unit tests and inside `test_helper.rb`.

It appears to be doing something when I run the command though as it takes a few seconds to finish.

Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be due to the `config/application.rb` file.

This Rails project was specifying frameworks individually, and `test_unit` was commented out.

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Comment: Mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, Rails 4 - you have my condolences.